# Memory questions for NodeJs in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, heroku, memory-management

How are you?

I'm creating this application that has to download like a 1000 photos and resize them.

I'm using mikeal's request package to download the images, and graphics magick to resize them. 
Also I'm using promises to paralellize the process.

The thing is that heroku fails and says

```
2017-03-07T18:06:54.958796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=701M(136.4%)

2017-03-07T18:06:54.958796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

I'm on the free plan and since it's an app for my own use I'd like to able not to pay for more memory.

How can I refactor my code so I don't run out of memory?

My code looks something like this:

```
var request = require('request')
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp')
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path');
var randomstring = require('randomstring');
var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
var util = require('util')
var gm = require('gm');
var sqldb = require('../../sqldb');
var MlStock = sqldb.MlStock;


 MlStock.findAll({})
  .then(fixProductsImages)

function fixProductsImages(products) {
 return Promise.all(products.map(fixProductImages))
}

function fixProductImages(product) {
 return Promise.all(product.imageVariations.map(makeImageLocal))
 .then((imageVariations)=>{
  // console.log('Updating product images: ', product, '\n', imageVariations)
  product.update({
    imageVariations: imageVariations
  })
 })
}

function makeImageLocal(imageObject) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request({ url: imageObject.url, encoding: 'binary' }, function(err, res, body) {
   if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    resolve(imageObject);
   };
   mkdirp(path.join(appDir, 'tempImages'), function(err) {
    var random = randomstring.generate();
    var imagePath = path.join(appDir, 'tempImages') + '/' + random + '.jpg';
    fs.writeFile(imagePath, body, 'binary', function(err) {
     if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      resolve(imageObject);
     };
     gm(imagePath)
      .fuzz(1, 1)
      .trim()
      .resize(500, 500)
      .gravity('Center')
      .extent(500, 500)
      .compress('BZip')
      .write(imagePath, function(err) {
       if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        resolve(imageObject);
       };
       console.log("The file was saved!  -- ", imagePath);
       resolve({ url: imagePath })
      });
    });
   })
  })
 })
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking that?

Comment: Just edited an added that portion of the code! thanks :)

Comment: Have you deleted `node_modules` or placed it in .gitignore?

Comment: yes, node_modules aren't pushed to heroku. Only the package.json. I'm using yeoman's generator-angular-fullstack for reference of architecture